# HTMLElement Custom Event

Tags: javascript

I create a custom event ex. `var event = new Event('hello');`, 
add listener to nodes

```
div1.addEventListener('hello', /*cb1*/);
div2.addEventListener('hello', /*cb2*/);
div3.addEventListener('hello', /*cb3*/);
```

and how to `dispatch` my event? I would like to call `event.dispatch()` and `cb1`, `cb2` and `cb3` should be called

Comment: So where did you stuck? `div1.dispatchEvent(event)`

Comment: Read this article.....https://gomakethings.com/custom-events-with-vanilla-javascript/ ...... this will answer all your questions

Comment: You need to dispatch 3 events...

Answer (score 1):

Just create `Event` using `new Event('hello');` and dispatch them one by one for each div.

```js
div1.addEventListener('hello', function(){
  console.log( "Event called for " + this.id );
});
div2.addEventListener('hello', function(){
  console.log( "Event called for " + this.id );
});
div3.addEventListener('hello', function(){
  console.log( "Event called for " + this.id );
});

var event = new Event('hello');
div1.dispatchEvent( event );
div2.dispatchEvent( event );
div3.dispatchEvent( event );
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <div id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this solution was obvious :) I am thinking about situation when I don't know which elements listen on my event, something like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/function-events-extension but for DOM elements

Comment: But someone has to trigger the `event` and you need to ensure that *someone* knows who has registered listeners for this event.

Comment: You can bind it the document instead of each div.